# Why won't my <mat-select> have the specified value selected when loaded?

Tags: angular-material, angular-ngmodel

I've created a form to edit data in a table.  Several fields of the form are drop down lists (mat-select) that are populated from other tables in a database.  I'm populating the drop downs (mat-select) successfully, but I'm struggling to set the selected value to match the data from the row that the user is intending to edit.

I actually have one dialog working, but for some reason a more complex dialog (with 3 drop downs) is not working.  I was originally only setting the ngModel, but I've added in the [comparewith] in hopes of resolving the problem or learning more.  My compare method always receives a null value for the second parameter.

certificationEdit.dialog.html:

```html
       <div class="form">
            <mat-form-field>
                <mat-label>Connector - {{m_connectorid}}</mat-label>
                <mat-select [(ngModel)]="m_connectorid" [value]="m_connectorid" [compareWith]="compareConnector" required>
                    <mat-option *ngFor="let item of connectorList" [value]="item.id"> {{item.connector}} ({{item.id}}) </mat-option>
                </mat-select>
            </mat-form-field>
        </div>
```

certificationEdit.dialog.component.ts:

```js
export class CertificationEditDialogComponent {

  connectorList = [];
  m_connectorid: string;

  ngOnInit() {

    this.databaseService.loadConnectorList().subscribe(response => {

      this.connectorList = response as any[];
    });

  }

  compareConnector(obj1: string, obj2: string) {
    return obj1 === obj2;
  }

  constructor(
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<CertificationEditDialogComponent>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: CERTIFICATION,
    public databaseService: DatabaseService
  ) {
    this.m_connectorid = this.data.connectorid;
   }
```

The code opening the edit dialog:

```js
    public CertificationStartEdit(
        i: number,
        id: string,
        releaseid: string,
        productid: string,
        connectorid: string,
        certtype: string,
        driverversion: string,
        certdate: string,
        changeneeded: string,
        comments: string
    ) {
        //this.release = release;
        this.index = i;
        const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(CertificationEditDialogComponent, {
            data: {
                id: id,
                releaseid: releaseid,
                productid: productid,
                connectorid: connectorid,
                certtype: certtype,
                driverversion: driverversion,
                certdate: certdate,
                changeneeded: changeneeded,
                comments: comments
            }
        });
```

The label shows m_connectorid has the value I expect, and the drop down list shows the id used for the value has the value I expect. None the less, the value I expect to be selected is not being selected.

Comment: is it possible that, mat-option.value is simply a number and you compare to a string? if you do == instrad of === in your comparator and it works. that’s the issue. other than that, I see no fault in the code

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't bind to both `ngModel` and `value` - use one only, in your case `ngModel` because you are using template forms (if using reactive forms use `formControl` or `formControlName` instead).

Because of `ngModel`/forms, using `MatSelect.value` to determine what is selected might not work. I'm not sure if that's a bug or if it just isn't designed to work that way. Instead you should use `MatSelect.selected.value` (single selection) or just the bound variable `m_connectorid` or `MatSelect.ngControl.value`.

Comment: I only recently added the binding with value, when I remove it, the problem still occurs (I'll double check, but I have 99.9% confidence in that statement).  You lost me a little on the MatSelect.ngControl.value talk.  should I try setting the value I want selected by setting that somewhere?  If so, where do you suggest setting that?

Comment: I think it's not selection that's the problem, it's how you are testing it. When using forms or `NgModel`, don't rely on `MatSelect.value` either as an input or a property. I'm not clear on how you determined that "the value I expect to be selected is not being selected." I assumed you are relying on `MatSelect.value` (or is it a UI problem?). `m_connectorid` has the correct value, and that is your model, so the `value` property doesn't matter. Check `MatSelect.selected.value` to make sure it matches - that proves the selection is correct.